# onMouseOver event doesn't work on canvas / d3 (tooltip)

Tags: dictionary, d3.js, canvas, tooltip, onmouseover

I'm using canvas and d3 to draw a map of ~130,000 points.
I want a tooltip to display data over the map's positions. However I don't see the tooltip nor the console log.

I'm at loss, any help would be appreciated :)

```
function createMap(dataset) {

  var dataBinding = locations.selectAll("points.arc")
    .data(dataset)

        .enter()
      .append("points")
      .classed("arc", true)
      .attr("x", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[0]})
      .attr("y", function(d) {return projection([d.y,d.x])[1]})
      .attr("radius", 1)
      .attr("fillStyle", "rgba(250, 80, 80, 1)")
      //onmouse over
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log("mouse over");
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.y + "<br/>"  + d.x) 
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

        })              
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);
        });

  drawCanvas();
}
```

Comment: No console log then it means it never go into mouseover function. Are you sure you want to use append("points")?

Comment: Append points works pretty well. It later translates into canvas arcs.
I understand that the best way to go about this is using XY values but I'm not sure how precisely.

Comment: Are you using canvas? I doubt that since "points" is not a common html elements, it might be the cause... but I am not sure

Comment: yes it later continues to this code:


    function drawCanvas() {

 var elements = locations.selectAll("points.arc");
   elements.each(function(d) {
    var node = d3.select(this);
 
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    context.beginPath();
        
  context.arc(node.attr("x"), node.attr("y"), node.attr("radius"), 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle = node.attr("fillStyle");
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
 })
    }

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion with you, I think canvas-based drawing for d3 is not supported with usual mouse event. My source of info:

https://bocoup.com/blog/d3js-and-canvas

To quote the important part:

> If you’ve been paying attention, you’re probably asking yourself now
>   “what about mouse events?!” Good call. Sadly, this approach does not
>   allow us to use the wonderful on event listener that we can normally
>   attach to selections and react to. The most we can do is attach a
>   mouse listener to the canvas element itself, get the x and y
>   coordinates of the pointer and proceed to resolve that somehow
>   ourselves.

Comment: Well one possible solution is to use the canvas element and overlay that with svg where canvas only exists within the margins, draw the axes in svg and plot the data in canvas, use the svg mouse event handlers to get x and y coordinates and do something about those in the canvas, what do you think about this structure https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/VGjyxo